# SQL Server and auto conversions?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to turn off implicit type conversion in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7605131/is-there-a-way-to-turn-off-implicit-type-conversion-in-sql-server)

With all the respect to SQL Server - which is trying to "*help*" me by auto conversions :

How can I make commands like these to *fail* ? :

```
SELECT 1+1+'2'   --4
SELECT '2'+1+1   --4
SELECT 1+'2'+1   --4
```

Comment: How do you want it to fail? You could change the `'2'` to `'2.0'`, and you'll get `Syntax error converting the varchar value '2.0' to a column of data type int.` Not sure if that's exactly what you're looking for, though, or if you want SQL Server to simply stop doing some/all implicit conversions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, although it's [requested feature](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQL/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=260762). The problem was already discussed on SO: [Is there a way to turn off implicit type conversion in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7605131/is-there-a-way-to-turn-off-implicit-type-conversion-in-sql-server)