# Why does an integer datatype variable accept a string value in a stored procedure in SQL Server? how to solve it?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

I have create a stored procedure with a parameter `@ID` of type `integer`, and when I pass an integer type value in form of `varchar` then it accept it.

How to validate it so that it doesn't accept integer value in varchar form like `@id='123'`?

Comment: Please review this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7605131/is-there-a-way-to-turn-off-implicit-type-conversion-in-sql-server

Comment: The value will be implicitly converted, when possible, by ether T-SQL like @Larnu's answer or by the client API when the parameter value is set in the client application. You can implement validation and/or type safety in the app code as desired.

Answer (score 1):

It accepts it because the value is implicitly cast, to an `int`, before the value is assigned to the parameter. `'123'` can be implicitly cast to an `int` successfully, so the statement works fine. I don't see any problems with that behaviourm, as it's both expected and documented in [Data type precedence (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

If you were to pass a value that couldn't be implicitly cast to an `int`, such as `'123.0'`, `'10e2'`, `'sardines'`, the statement would error due to the implicit conversion failing.